# How to ignore DTD parsing in Apache's AXIOM

Tags: xml, axiom

In my xml document , doctype is present. While parsing the xml document using Apache Axiom , it throws an following error msg "org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Cannot create OMDocType because the XMLStreamReader doesn't support the DTDReader extension".

```
   XMLStreamReader parser = null;
  try {
    StAXParserConfiguration standalone = StAXParserConfiguration.STANDALONE;
   parser= StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(standalone, in);
   // parser = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);
  }
  catch (XMLStreamException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (FactoryConfigurationError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  StAXOMBuilder builder=new StAXOMBuilder(parser);
  OMElement rootOMElement = builder.getDocumentElement();
```

Comment: Removing the doctype from the document will resolve this problem . But i want Axiom parser to take care this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in Axiom 1.2.16 (see [AXIOM-475](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-475)). In the meantime you can work around this issue by using Woodstox (4.0 or above) as StAX implementation.

Comment: Hi Andreas, It seems you have resolved this issue. Could you please provide an example code.